# Algorithms for range query on streams of integers

Tags: algorithm, range-query

I'm getting a stream of positive integers to my program. I've to store them as I receive them and be able to answer to range queries that come in between.

A simple solution that came to my mind is to store integers in a hashtable where keys are character representation of the integers(keys must be strings in my hashtable).
Then, whenever a range query [a, b] comes, I can simply loop from a to b, check whether key exists and retrieve the value if it does. However, I'm not sure if this is a good approach.

What other alternative solutions exists for this problem?

Comment: I am sure this is not a good approach.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes but compared to what?

Comment: @SpiderRico do we know the constraints on the streams of integers, like what is the maximum integer value that will be present in the stream, something like that ?

Comment: @zenwraight Nope, we don't know the maximum/minimum value. However, we know they are positive. I'll update the question to note that fact.

Answer (score 0):

If you maintained an ordered list of the integers from the stream read so far, then a range query can be done by finding `a` (using binary search) and iterating from that point until you pass `b`, so that the time spent on the query will be proportional to the actual size of the result, regardless of how sparse the range is filled.

Comment: This is a valid alternative and I will try it but can we  say this is strictly better than my naive solution? This one has a insertion time, right?

Comment: You'd need a pretty contrived or trivially-sized problem for this to not be better.

Comment: @SpiderRico how about using a balanced search tree like AVL tree where the insertion time will be log(n) ?